# Get all the data from a datagrid and export them in CSV

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid

like the title says, in my soft in need to print my datagrid into a CSV file. The datas are coming from a serialport but it's not really important.
What I would like to know is how can i find my datas in my datagrid. With this following code it's probably going to be more clear.

```
    private void ConvertCSV_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Write sample data to CSV file
        using (CsvFileWriter writer = new CsvFileWriter("C:\\Users\\stagiaire\\Desktop\\WriteTest.csv"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DGImpulse.Items.Count-1; i++)
            {
                CsvRow row = new CsvRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < #I need the number of column here (it's currently 4)#; j++)
                    row.Add(#I need the element of my row here, like Element of the Cell1, etc#);
                writer.WriteRow(row);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm in C# WPF

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export DataGrid into CSV or Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957556/export-datagrid-into-csv-or-excel)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343523/csv-export-from-datagrid-wrong-rows?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following blog post.

**How to export data from a DataGrid in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/09/29/export-data-from-a-datagrid/

It should contain all information you need to be able to export the data displayed in `DataGrid` to a CSV file.